# How to prevent double addtobackstack while on PreferencesFragment in android

Tags: android

**Background:**

I'm using PreferencesFragment to manage preferences in my android app and i use options menu to access those preferences.

*MainActivity class overriden methods:*

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.menu_prefs:
        PrefsFragment prefs = new PrefsFragment();
        getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.main_container, prefs)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

*res/menu/menu.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_prefs"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
    android:title="@string/menu_prefs_title"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText">
</item>

</menu>
```

**Problem:**

- While on main screen, I click preferences icon in action bar, PrefsFragment starts.
- While on PrefsFragment, I click preferences icon in action bar PrefsFragment starts **again** (this is where problem arise).
- I hit the back button and it reverts fragment transaction and goes back to **PrefsFragment**. (it should go back to main screen).

**Question:**
Is there any smart way to disable double showing PrefsFragment?

**Desired outcome:**
Clicking prefs icon in action bar if on main screen shows PrefsFragement, clicking prefs icon in action bar while PrefsFragemnt is visible does nothing, clicking back button while on PrefsFragment always goes back to main screen.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after some more digging I did this:

I'm disabling action bar/options menu if PrefsFragemnt is visible ( I could add different menu here but disabling it works fine in this case ).

*PrefsFragment.java*

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

public class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
}
```

*MainActivity.java (overriden methods):*

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    PrefsFragment prefs = (PrefsFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("PREFS");
    if (prefs != null){
        if (prefs.isVisible()) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.menu_prefs:
        PrefsFragment prefs = new PrefsFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        manager 
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.main_container, prefs, "PREFS")
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
        manager.executePendingTransactions();
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The most important part is calling `manager.executePendingTransactions()` and `invalidateOptionsMenu()` on button click and calling `invalidateOptionsMenu()` when stopping fragment. This will cause for menu to be refreshed evry time we go to prefs and after getting out of them.

If you have better solutions I would **love** to see them, as this one feels a little bit hackish to me.

Comment: Grzegorz, nice work :-). shame android doesn't have anything "built in" for this very common use case.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to accomplish it using FragmentTransaction.detach?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#detach%28android.app.Fragment%29